# Get foreign key value in printed table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to print out my foreign keys from another table when I get the results from my query and print it in a table.

My connect and query code:

```
        $host="localhost";
        $username="****";
        $password="****";
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db('****')or DIE(mysql_error());
        $tbl_name="ticket";

        $sql = "SELECT `id`, `subject`, `assigned`, `status`, `created`, `priority_id` FROM $tbl_name";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

This is the code for printing out the results in a table

```
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
        print ('<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">');
        print ("<thead>");
        print ("<th>ID</th>");
        print ("<th>SUBJECT</th>");
        print ("<th>ASSIGNED</th>");
        print ("<th>STATUS</th>");
        print ("<th>CREATED</th>");
        print ("<th>PRIORITY</th>");
        print ("</tr> </thead>");
        print ("<tbody>");
        while ($row) {
            $id = $row['id'];

            print ('<tr>'); 
            foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                print ("<td data-href=tickets/edit.php?id=$id>$value</td>");
            }
            print ("</tr>");

            //Fetch next row    
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        }
        print ("</tbody>");
        print ("</table>"); 

        mysql_free_result($result);
```

So the priority ID in the ticket table is a foreign key to a "priority" table where I have three different rows

```
id     name
 1     low
 2     medium
 3     high
```

And the same for the assigned ID in the ticket table. This is a name of a person which the ticket is assigned to. It is stored in a "members" table

```
id     name
 1     John
 2     Ben
 3     Brad
```

How would I go about this? I tried inner join, but with no luck.

(Also I know I should use mysqli, but had some issues with it. This worked, so I might change it later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.id, t.subject, m.name AS memberName, t.status, t.created, p.name AS priorityName 
        FROM $tbl_name AS t
        LEFT JOIN priority AS p ON t.priority_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN members AS m ON t.assigned = m.id";
```

Edited: I forgot the ON in the second LEFT JOIN. I just added.

Comment: The reason I didn't use INNER JOIN is just in case if a ticket has no assigned and/or priority. So they will be still listed but with missing member and priority values.